# Create Set of IDs based on Varying ID Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a collection of tables that have missing document ID ranges. The `Start Range` is the beginning ID, the `End Range` is the ending ID, and the `Missing` is the number of rows within that range that are missing (includes the beginning and end ID within its count). I was wondering how I can go about parsing into a new table the individual IDs as opposed to the actual range based on the `Missing` column.

This is how the data is presented:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Start Range | End Range | Missing | Date      |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 184         | 186       | 3       | 1/9/1979  |
| 204         | 207       | 4       | 1/9/1979  |
| 209         | 212       | 4       | 1/9/1979  |
| 223         | 224       | 2       | 1/9/1979  |
| 240         | 241       | 2       | 1/10/1979 |
| 243         | 243       | 1       | 1/10/1979 |
| 248         | 249       | 2       | 1/10/1979 |
| 261         | 265       | 5       | 1/11/1979 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

I am looking to acheive output as such:

```
+-----+-----------+
| ID  | Date      |
+-----+-----------+
| 184 | 1/9/1979  |
| 185 | 1/9/1979 |
| 186 | 1/9/1979 |
| 204 | 1/9/1979 |
| 205 | 1/9/1979 |
| 206 | 1/9/1979 |
| 207 | 1/9/1979 |
| 209 | 1/9/1979 |
| 210 | 1/9/1979 |
| 211 | 1/9/1979 |
| 212 | 1/9/1979 |
| 223 | 1/9/1979 |
| 224 | 1/9/1979 |
| 240 | 1/10/1979 |
| 241 | 1/10/1979 |
| 243 | 1/10/1979 |
| 248 | 1/10/1979 |
| 249 | 1/10/1979 |
| 261 | 1/11/1979 |
| 262 | 1/11/1979 |
| 263 | 1/11/1979 |
| 264 | 1/11/1979 |
| 265 | 1/11/1979 |
+-----+-----------+
```

What would be the best method to achieve this? Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: A numbers or tally table would be the easiest approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a UDF to generate ranges, but a numbers table or tally table would do the trick as well

```
Declare @Table table (StartRange int,EndRange int,Date Date)
Insert into @Table values
(184,186,'1979-01-09'),
(204,207,'1979-01-09')


Select B.ID
      ,A.Date
 From @Table A
 Join (Select ID=cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](1,9999,1)) B
   on B.ID between A.StartRange and A.EndRange
 Order by B.ID,Date
```

Returns

```
ID  Date
184 1979-01-09
185 1979-01-09
186 1979-01-09
204 1979-01-09
205 1979-01-09
206 1979-01-09
207 1979-01-09
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End
```

Comment: Perfect - this worked exactly as I needed. Thanks for teaching me something new, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help.  For the record Mike's post was on the mark as well

Answer (score 1):

Build a tally table or CTE. 
[tally table](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/&ved=0ahUKEwjTjae0hqvNAhVLC8AKHbQrBQMQFggkMAI&usg=AFQjCNGhNo4zzy4yRUuv5QOZwUEv5EJ3Tg&sig2=UtAkQpnGdFTXHIgqIU7rhA)

Which is just a single column of incrementing integers n

```
Select tally.n as Id,  missingRange.date
from tally
 inner join missingRange
On tally.n >= beginRange 
And tally.n <= endRange
```